# Receive the equation of the stat_smooth in ggplot2 R mtcars example

Tags: r, ggplot2, equation, coefficients

Hi I would like to know how can I retrieve the equation of stat_smooth either in the ggplot2 or in a vector or somewhere else. the code that I am using is:

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat)) 
p <- p + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="loess") 
p
```

Thanks

Comment: I think your only option is to get directly into the code of `stat_smooth`. What is your goal in the first place?

Comment: to use the equation (best fit) and generalize it for similar data fitting

Answer (score 2):

The `ggpmisc` package can be very usefull. However, it will not work with loess as loess doesn't give a formula. See here: [Loess Fit and Resulting Equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785118/loess-fit-and-resulting-equation)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = drat)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x) +
  stat_poly_eq(parse=T, aes(label = ..eq.label..), formula=y~x)
p
```

[image]

Comment: So is there any other alternative to the loess function? or not

Comment: loess is rather a visualization of the trend in your data. if you want a equation than I would recommend applying regression techniques like linear models, polynomial regression or generalized adaptive models (GAM). However in most cases you will need to define _a priori_ what is the relationship between your data eg y~x  or y~x+x^2. Here is nice disscussion regarding you question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550582/when-to-choose-nls-over-loess)